# Get facebook friends list, email and other details

Tags: facebook

I am using "taggable_friends" to get user's friends list, even if I give email, bday and work in the fields list, the request only returns user id and name. I am using Test Users to test taggable_friends.

Couple of questions:-

1. How to get email, bday and work profile of a friend?
2. I am unable to set a work profile of a test user, it shows an error "Cannot use this name, please use another name". How do I set and fetch a friends work history?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`taggable_friends` if for tagging only, you can´t use it for anything else. It does not let you access more than the name, and you only get a tagging token, not a User ID.

In order to get email, birthday and work profile of a friend, that friend needs to authorize your App with the neccessary permissions first.